# ignoring "collision" in a pacman game

Tags: c, assembly, pixel, pacman

i am almost done with my pixel pacman
and im trying to figure out how the monsters should avoid the collision with the power up and the energizer pills
if you run the game you will see dots which represents
yellow is the pacman
red are the ghosts
purple are simple pills
green are energizer pills(if you eat them you can eat the ghosts).
my problem here is that the im having hard time that the monsters will not "eat" the red or green dots. here is my main struct

```
struct info {
        int curX;
        int curY;
        char color;
        int alive;
    };
```

also every monster move is represented like this

```
if ( rand1 == 1){   //random up
                        if(infos[i].curY > 50){
                            for (j = 0 ;j < 18 ; j++){
                                set_board(infos[i].curX,infos[i].curY,0);                               
                                set_board(infos[i].curX,--infos[i].curY,4);
```

if the monster is the same location as the pixel it will override it( a thing that i dont want to happen)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your issue is a display one, not a game logic one. From what I understand, when the ghost goes over the pellets, they get erased. It seems that the answer here is simply to redraw the pellets *after* the ghost goes over them. You call this pixel pacman: does that mean that every entity is a displayed as a one pixel ? If so, the solution is simply to turn the pixel back to its original colour instead of black (I guess that is the colour you chose when there is nothing to display) when the ghost has moved to the next location.